# What if an if-statement is equal to error?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, syntax-error, dictionary

In checking for amicable numbers I've made the following *if*-statement (dict is dictionary):

```
if n == dict[lib[n]]:
        amic[n] = dict[n]
```

But if the *n* value is not in the dictionary it returns an error; as it should. But I'd like it to continue because an error means "it's not equal" and it should continue to the next *n*.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `dict.get()` which returns `None` (or another default of your choosing).  For example `n == lib.get(lib.get(n))`

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. I noticed I had confused library with dictionary (fixed it now), so kudos as well for seeing through that.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap in a try block, and ignore the exception, but given a bit more context, there's probably a better way... (`lib[lib[n]]` just looks odd...)

This will catch an IndexError for both `lib` and `amic` though...

```
try:
    if n == lib[lib[n]]:
        amic[n] = lib[n]
except IndexError as e: # or KeyError if a dict
    pass
```

Comment: You probably meant `amic[n] = lib[n]` there. Also, you might want to explain how you could avoid your caveat (e.g., by assigning `n == lib[lib[n]]` to a variable inside a `try`/`catch`, then using it in an `if`).

Comment: @abarnert you're welcome to correct my posts for typos like that :) Would love to explain further, but since context or anything further appears to be uncoming, it'd either be misleading, un-useful and a potential waste of time. Thanks for pointing out the typo though.